# Unexpected change of servlet path while handling a POST request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm new to SpringBoot, and trying to implement Spring Security with JWT. I have problem and I think it has something to do with JWT filter and security config.

I tried debugging Spring Security by setting `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` in my `SecurityConfig.java`, and I found something wrong. When I send a POST request that does signup user, somehow the servlet path changes in the middle of the request.

```
Request received for POST '/auth/signup':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@63af20a

servletPath:/auth/signup
pathInfo:null
headers: 
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
accept: */*
postman-token: 25e5cac3-a91f-40a4-8a3e-20a541aff803
host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------054882976756079921653325
cookie: JSESSIONID=E2A8E65C25C184D47724FBA022FBAA94
content-length: 149066


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtAuthorizationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2024-02-25T20:46:06.469+09:00  INFO 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.c.login.jwt.JwtAuthorizationFilter   : ===doFilterInternal Started===
2024-02-25T20:46:06.469+09:00  INFO 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.c.login.jwt.JwtAuthorizationFilter   : ===request path: /auth/signup===
2024-02-25T20:46:06.470+09:00  INFO 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.c.login.jwt.JwtAuthorizationFilter   : contains 'auth'
2024-02-25T20:46:06.644+09:00 DEBUG 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        u1_0.user_id,
        u1_0.created_date,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.modified_date,
        u1_0.nickname,
        u1_0.profile_image,
        u1_0.refresh_token,
        u1_0.role,
        u1_0.self_description,
        u1_0.social_id,
        u1_0.social_login_type,
        u1_0.social_refresh_token 
    from
        user u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.social_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.user_id,
        u1_0.created_date,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.modified_date,
        u1_0.nickname,
        u1_0.profile_image,
        u1_0.refresh_token,
        u1_0.role,
        u1_0.self_description,
        u1_0.social_id,
        u1_0.social_login_type,
        u1_0.social_refresh_token 
    from
        user u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.social_id=?
2024-02-25T20:46:06.664+09:00 DEBUG 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.cookieeserver.login.OAuthService     : OAuthService, signup - 이미 존재하는 사용자
2024-02-25T20:46:06.693+09:00 DEBUG 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.c.cookieeserver.login.OAuthController  : 이미 존재하는 사용자입니다.
2024-02-25T20:46:06.703+09:00  INFO 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/auth/auth/signup':

org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest@657cc2d2

servletPath:/auth/auth/signup
pathInfo:null
headers: 
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
accept: */*
postman-token: 25e5cac3-a91f-40a4-8a3e-20a541aff803
host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------054882976756079921653325
cookie: JSESSIONID=E2A8E65C25C184D47724FBA022FBAA94
content-length: 149066


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtAuthorizationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2024-02-25T20:46:06.709+09:00  INFO 92709 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for POST '/error':

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@746c5161

servletPath:/error
pathInfo:null
headers: 
user-agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.1
accept: */*
postman-token: 25e5cac3-a91f-40a4-8a3e-20a541aff803
host: localhost:8080
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------054882976756079921653325
cookie: JSESSIONID=E2A8E65C25C184D47724FBA022FBAA94
content-length: 149066


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  JwtAuthorizationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************
```

You can see that the url changes from `/auth/signup` to `/auth/auth/signup`. I have no idea how this has happened, but I'm guess if it has to do with Multipart..? And the result that I get from this is

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2024-02-25T11:46:06.710+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/auth/signup"
}
```

Just in case, I'll put up some codes that I think are related to this problem.

`SecurityConfig.java`

```java
package com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.config;

import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.jwt.JwtAuthorizationFilter;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.jwt.JwtService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint;  // 빈으로 등록된 엔트리 포인트 주입받음. 즉, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint 주입

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.info("=== SecurityFilterChain Started ===");
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // 서버에 인증정보를 저장하지 않기 때문에 csrf 보안을 사용X
                // JWT를 사용하기 때문에 세션을 사용하지 않는 설정.(아래)
                .sessionManagement(config -> config.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // form 기반 로그인 비활성화
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)  // rest api이므로 basic auth 및 csrf 보안을 사용하지 않는 설정
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        registry -> registry
                                // permitAll()은 권한에만 신경 쓰지 않을 뿐 똑같이 모든 필터를 거침
                                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                // JWT 인증을 위하여 직접 구현한 jwtAuthorizationFilter 필터를 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter 전에 실행
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // exception handler
                .exceptionHandling(handler -> handler.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint));
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthorizationFilter jwtAuthorizationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthorizationFilter(jwtService);
    }
}
```

`JwtAuthorizationFilter.java`

```java
package com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.jwt;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static com.cookiee.cookieeserver.global.Constant.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    /**
     * doFilter와 같지만 요청 당 한번만 실행되는 것이 보장됨.
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @param filterChain
     * @throws ServletException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log.info("===doFilterInternal Started===");

        String servletPath = request.getServletPath();
        log.info("===request path: {}===", servletPath);

        // 1. Request Header에서 토큰 추출
        final String headerValue = request.getHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION);

        if (servletPath.contains("auth")) {
            log.info("contains 'auth'");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            try {
                // 2. 토큰 유효성 검사 (Bearer로 시작하고 값이 있으면)
                if (headerValue != null && headerValue.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
                    String accessToken = headerValue.substring(TOKEN_PREFIX.length());
                    // 정상 토큰이면 해당 토큰으로 authentication을 가져와 SecurityContext에 저장
                    if (jwtService.validate(accessToken)) {
                        log.info("[Authorization Filter] Normal JWT");
                        Authentication authentication = getAuthentication(accessToken);
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JwtException e) {
                log.debug("===Exception===");
                request.setAttribute("exception", e);
                jwtExceptionHandler(response, e);
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    // 권한 가져오기
    public Authentication getAuthentication(String accessToken) {
        Claims claims = jwtService.getTokenClaims(accessToken);
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities =
                Arrays.stream(new String[]{claims.get(AUTHORITIES_KEY).toString()})
                        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        User principal = new User(claims.getSubject(), "", authorities);
        log.debug("=== getting {} authentication ===", principal);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, accessToken, authorities);
    }

    // jwt 예외 처리
    public void jwtExceptionHandler(HttpServletResponse response, Throwable error) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<>();
        body.put("message", error.getMessage());
        body.put("isSuccess", false);
        body.put("code", HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), body);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

`OAuthController.java`

```java
package com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login;

import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.global.StatusCode;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.global.dto.BaseResponseDto;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.global.dto.DataResponseDto;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.global.dto.ErrorResponseDto;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.dto.request.UserSignupRequestDto;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.dto.response.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.jwt.JwtHeaderUtil;
import com.cookiee.cookieeserver.login.jwt.JwtService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuthController {
    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final OAuthService oAuthService;

    /**
     * 새로 가입한 사용자가 소셜 로그인 후 회원 정보 입력할 때
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping(value = "/auth/signup", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    public BaseResponseDto<?> signup(UserSignupRequestDto userSignupRequestDto) {
        try{
            OAuthResponse response = oAuthService.signup(userSignupRequestDto);
            log.info("[OAuthController] response: {}", response);
            return DataResponseDto.of(response);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
            return ErrorResponseDto.of(StatusCode.INTERNAL_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * 회원 탈퇴
     * @return
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/auth/signout")
    public BaseResponseDto<?> signout() throws Exception {
        String accessToken = JwtHeaderUtil.getAccessToken();
        Long userId = jwtService.getUserId(accessToken);

        oAuthService.signout(userId);
        return DataResponseDto.of(null, "회원 탈퇴에 성공하였습니다.");
    }

    /**
     * 액세스 토큰 갱신
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @PostMapping("/auth/refresh")
    public BaseResponseDto<?> refresh() {
        try {
            AccessTokenResponse response = jwtService.reissueAccessToken();
            return DataResponseDto.of(response);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return ErrorResponseDto.of(StatusCode.VALIDATION_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * 로그아웃
     */
//    @PutMapping("/logout")
//    public BaseResponseDto<?> logout() {
//
//    }
}
```

`UserSignupRequestDto` has `MultipartFile` field.

FYI, my project is only using social login(google and apple).

I need help so bad

Comment: I think your problem might be that you still continue the filterChain when you catch an exception and modify the response. So it might do some weird stuff. You shouldn't continue the filterChain when you catch a JwtException. The original error might not appear in your logs

Comment: Ok, so I tried putting `filterChain.doFilter(request, response);` inside try block, but it's the same, still getting an error and debug that says `Request received for POST '/auth/auth/signup':` I just don't know where that additional `/auth` in the path came from.

Comment: Ok I didn't read your code well enough, can you show your OAuthController ? Isn't there an exception occurring there or a redirection ?

Comment: Ok, I added the code at the end of my question.

Comment: Your OAuthController answers an error no? You don't write the stackTrace only its message I guess. I mean throw an exception